# The values of the parameters for which $\frac{ab}{c}+\frac{a(a+1)b(b+1)}{2!c(c+1)}+\frac{a(a+1)(a+2)b(b+1)(b+2)}{3!c(c+1)(c+2)}+\dots$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Determine the values of the parameters for which $\frac{ab}{c}+\frac{a(a+1)b(b+1)}{2!c(c+1)}+\frac{a(a+1)(a+2)b(b+1)(b+2)}{3!c(c+1)(c+2)}+\dots$ converges.

Then $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(a+n)(b+n)}{(n+1)(c+n)}$, I guess then I should use Raabe's test, but I don't know how to write $\frac{(a+n)(b+n)}{(n+1)(c+n)}$ in form of $1-\frac{p}{n}$. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\frac{(a+n)(b+n)}{(c+n)(1+n)} = 1 - \frac{1+c-a-b}{n} + O(1/n^2)
$$
as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Thanks, but how did you get $1 - \frac{1+c-a-b}{n}$ part?

Comment: Long division..

Comment: Would you mind explain how to use long division here?

Comment: You can replace $n$ by $1/x$ and expand you fraction into a Taylor series around $x=0$. Returning to the original variable $n$ gives you the asymptotics of the fraction for large $n$.